# How to parallelize this code?

Tags: matrix, parallelization, side-effect

Initialize a matrix `a` with value of $\alpha$ in central cell as "ice", and $\beta$ in every other cell.

```
L = 599; alpha = 0.501; beta = 0.3; gamma = 0.0001; 
a = ConstantArray[beta, {L, L}];
a[[Ceiling[L/2], Ceiling[L/2]]] = alpha;
```

Store all ice cell in `a1`, and store all water cell in `a2`.

```
a1 = ParallelMap[If[# >= alpha, # , 0] &, a, {2}];
a2 = ParallelMap[If[# < alpha, #, 0] &, a, {2}];
```

Now scan all the cells in `a`, copy all the ice cells and their neighbors into `a1`, put zeros in `a2` in these positions. Then add $\gamma$(growth rate) to non-zero cell in `a1`.

```
Do[If[Total[Boole[{a[[i, j]] >= alpha, a[[i, j + 1]] >= alpha, 
  a[[i, j - 1]] >= alpha, a[[i + 1, j]] >= alpha, 
  a[[i + 1, j + 1]] >= alpha, a[[i + 1, j - 1]] >= alpha, 
  a[[i - 1, j]] >= alpha, a[[i - 1, j + 1]] >= alpha, 
  a[[i - 1, j - 1]] >= alpha}]] >= 1, 
a1[[i, j]] = a[[i, j]] + gamma; a2[[i, j]] = 0;, 
a2[[i, j]] = a[[i, j]]; a1[[i, j]] = 0;], {i, 2, L - 1}, {j, 2, L - 1}];
```

And I got(For `L=9`)

```
a1 // MatrixForm
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0.3001  0.3001  0.3001  0   0   0
0   0   0   0.3001  0.5011  0.3001  0   0   0
0   0   0   0.3001  0.3001  0.3001  0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
a2 // MatrixForm
0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3
0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3
0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3
0.3 0.3 0.3 0   0   0   0.3 0.3 0.3
0.3 0.3 0.3 0   0   0   0.3 0.3 0.3
0.3 0.3 0.3 0   0   0   0.3 0.3 0.3
0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3
0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3
0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3
```

The result is correct, but it's very slow when `L` is large.I tried to use `ParallelDo` instead of `Do`, but there is side effect.
I was wondering if it's possible to parallelize the above code?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You're trying to get better performance or simply play with parallelism? BTW your original code contains mistake, `Boole[{a[[i, j]] >= alpha, a[[i, j + 1]] >= alpha, a[[i, j - 1]] >= alpha, 
   a[[i + 1, j]] >= alpha, a[[i + 1, j + 1]] >= alpha, a[[i + 1, j - 1]] >= alpha, 
   a[[i - 1, j]] >= alpha, a[[i - 1, j + 1]] >= alpha, a[[i - 1, j - 1]] >= alpha}] >= 0` won't work as you wished. (If you still don't understand what's wrong, try `Boole[{True, False}] >= 0`.) Also, I don't think the rest part of the code inside `Do` is the correct interpretation of your description.

Comment: @xzczd I forgot to put a `Total` before `Boole`, the rest part of the code inside `Do` is simply separating `a` into `a1` and `a2`, where `a1` contains all ice and it's neighbor, and `a2` contains all the other cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that you're just trying to make the code faster, then try this:

```
L = 599; alpha = 0.501; beta = 0.3; gamma = 0.0001;

a = ConstantArray[beta, {L, L}];
a[[Ceiling[L/2], Ceiling[L/2]]] = alpha;
{a1, a2} = {a #, a (1 - #)} &@ UnitStep[a - alpha];

{Function[{x, y}, a1[[x - 1 ;; x + 1, y - 1 ;; y + 1]] = 
                  a[[x - 1 ;; x + 1, y - 1 ;; y + 1]]] @@@#, 
 Function[{x, y}, a2[[x - 1 ;; x + 1, y - 1 ;; y + 1]] = 0.] @@@#}&@Position[a, alpha];
a1 = (1 - UnitStep[-#]) gamma + # &@a1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Like xzczd I suggest you create the initial arrays using [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep.html)to define a binary mask:

```
L = 599; alpha = 0.501; beta = 0.3; gamma = 0.0001;
a = ConstantArray[beta, {L, L}];
a[[Ceiling[L/2], Ceiling[L/2]]] = alpha;

With[{mask = UnitStep[a - alpha]},
  a1 = mask a;
  a2 = (1 - mask) a];
```

A similar approach can be used to replace the `Do` loop. The loop goes through each element of `a` and works out if that element or any of its neighbours is greater than alpha. This is equivalent to asking if the *maximum* value of the element and its neighbours is greater than alpha. You can use [`MaxFilter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxFilter.html)for that, and then `UnitStep` again to create a binary mask:

```
With[{mask = UnitStep[MaxFilter[a, 1] - alpha]},
  a1 = mask (a + gamma);
  a2 = (1 - mask) a];
```

This is much faster than the procedural `Do` loop.

Comment: Oh, I always forget those image processing functions can be used for list manipulation!